# How to show service data immediately when it is received with $http without using angular.copy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a service, which should save me the specific data that I load from a JSON file. I want the data to show on the page as soon as it's received.
I created a $scope variable to be equal to the data in the service, the data is not shown immediately on the page.

I only achieved my goal when using: `angular.copy(response.data, this.animals)`,
but I do not understand why it is not working when I am using: `this.animals = response.data`. I would like to know why this is happening and what is the difference.

```js
module.service("animalService", function($http) {
    this.animals=[];
    $http.get('animals.json').then(function(response) {
        //this.animals = response.data ----> not working
        angular.copy(response.data, this.animals)
    });
});

module.controller("animalController", function($scope, animalService) {
    //$scope.animals is what I use to create a table in html
    $scope.animals = animalService.aniamsl;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it right, try:

```
module.service("animalService", function($http) {
     return $http.get('animals.json')
});

module.controller("animalController", function($scope, animalService) {
    animalService.then(function(res){
       $scope.animals = res.data
    });
});
```

any `http` response returns `promise`, and what it means is that the data would come `asynchronously`. As per my understanding using `angular.copy` triggers a `digest` cycle and so the changes are detected but it's not at all a good practice. Prefer `promise` handling as I have shown in the above code

#### Update:

Since the variable is populated as a `promise` and it is to be used by other `controller`  , I would suggest to use events such as `$rootScope.emit` and `$rootScope.on` so that the `controllers` are notified about the change in value after `$http` is completed

Comment: but if a want to assign the received data to a variable in the service?
because i need to change the data in the service so i could use the same data in other controllers too.

Comment: @NoyGafni : Please check my update and let me know if it helps